# What different customizations are possible by using HttpHandlers in an ASP.NET application?

Tags: asp.net, httphandler, ihttphandler

Digging deeper into HttpHandlers I found they provide nice way to customize an ASP.NET application.  I am new to ASP.NET and I want to know about different customizations that are possible using HttpHandlers.  Lots of websites talk about how they are implemented but it would be nice to know some use cases beyond what ASP.NET already provides using HttpHandlers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ASPX page provides a base template (so to speak) for a form-based web page. By default, it outputs `text/html` and allows for easy adding of form elements and event handling for these elements.

In contrast, an HttpHandler is stripped to the bone. It is like a blank slate for HTTP requests. Therefore, an HttpHandler is good for many types of requests that do not necessarily require a web form. You could use an HttpHandler to output dynamic images, JSON, or many other MIME type results.

A couple examples:

1) You have a page which needs to make an AJAX call which will return a JSON response. An HttpHandler could be setup to handle this request and output the JSON.

2) You have a page which links to PDF documents that are stored as binary blobs in a database. An HttpHandler could be setup to handle this request and output the binary blob as a byte stream with a PDF MIME type for the content type.

Comment: Thanks.  Is it a good approach for videos? see my comment below.

Answer (score 1):

Check this page for a good example and code of why you might want to customize them: http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Range-Specific-Requests-in-ASP-NET.aspx  Essentially it can be used when you want to server certain files but not allow them to be accessible via a plain url (security).